# Grab cell data and use in "IF" statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

Is it possible to grab a cell containing a date and paste that date in an "IF" statement containing text, similar to the below:

> =IF(OR(I1=TRUE,J1=TRUE),"Date:___________________",IF(AND(I1=FALSE,J1=FALSE),"Date:________N/A_________"))

I have tried:

> =IF(OR(I1=TRUE,J1=TRUE),"Date:Sheet1!D2",IF(AND(I1=FALSE,J1=FALSE),"Date:________N/A_________"))

and also

> =IF(OR(I1=TRUE,J1=TRUE),"Date:=TODAY()",IF(AND(I1=FALSE,J1=FALSE),"Date:________N/A_________"))

But those display `Sheet1!D2` and `=TODAY()` respectively instead of the actual date in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `CONCATENATE` function to concatenate `Date:` and the value, like so:

```
=IF(OR(I1=TRUE,J1=TRUE),CONCATENATE("Date:",Sheet1!D2),IF(AND(I1=FALSE,J1=FALSE),"Date:________N/A_________"))
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it will do what I want with some fine tuning as it is currently giving me some random value, not the actual date, but atleast something is happening.I will ask for assistance again if I get lost. Thanks again

Comment: Great! Glad I could push you in the right direction.

Comment: You can also concatenate with an ampersand instead of the function: "Date:"&Sheet1!D2.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks! I did not know that.

Comment: @David: that "random" value is likely the "raw" stored date.  You may need to format the result as a date.

Comment: @fixer1234, yep, you are right about the formatting. Had to set it to "text". Thanks alot

Comment: @David: With the date buried inside a text string, formatting the cell might be a problem for an embedded date.  If so, you could do it with the [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58?CTT=1&CorrelationId=758d5092-8073-481b-9af6-f63e1876c837&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).  It would look something like: TEXT(Sheet1!D2,"dd/mm/yyy") in place of the cell reference.

Comment: @fixer1234, alright. Got it working with the TEXT function. Much appreciated

Comment: @imtheman: just noticed, this pushed you over 2K.  Congrats.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks! I've been working towards that for some time now. :)